# AngularJS Data inserted successfully but it display Error code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

I used Spring framework as a back-end and angular as a front end. When I try to insert data from the angualrJs value is inserted into database but display error code. please suggest me what is the wrong in this code.

```
var app = angular.module("categoryApp", []);
app.controller('submitCategory', [ '$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.submitClick = function() {
            var dataObj = {
                name : $scope.name
            };
            var result = $http.post("/tutorials/category", dataObj);
            result.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("success");
                $scope.message = data;
            });
            result.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({
                    data : data
                }));
            });

            $scope.name = '';
        }
    }
]);
```

And my html is

```
<body ng-app="categoryApp">
    <section class="panel" ng-controller="submitCategory">
        <header class="panel-heading"> Basic Forms </header>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form role="form" method="post" ng-submit="submitClick()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category">Category</label> <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="name"
                        placeholder="Category" ng-model="name">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

And my controller method is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/category", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> postCategory(@RequestBody Category category,
            Model model) {
        categoryService.save(category);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("success", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: You problem is with data binding can you show you view code (html)

Comment: aitnasser  I put my view part also can you please look it once.

Comment: I dont see where do you want to display  your data coming from server

Comment: I just alert the message in the angular code it alert the error message part but the data was inserted successfully

Comment: In your code java Change  ResponseEntity<String> by  ResponseEntity<Category>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by ResponseEntity<**String**>  .Your code java should be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/category", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public ResponseEntity<String> postCategory(@RequestBody Category category, 
            Model model) { 
    categoryService.save(category); 
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("success", HttpStatus.OK); }
```